# is it correct to use her in this sentence or should I use she?

Tags: pronouns

Which one is right?

> 1. like her being cleared.

> 2. like she being cleared.

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add the context or just provide a link to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use "she" or "her" in the following sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133443/should-i-use-she-or-her-in-the-following-sentence)

Comment: These look more like phrases than sentences to me. Neither makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken as an isolated sentence your 1

> like her being cleared.

is correct. "her being cleared" is the object of "like", and "she" would not be used in that construction. One could write:

> I like it that she was cleared

or better

> I am glad that she was cleared.

In general when a person is the subject of a verb we use "she" (or "he"). When the same person is the object, we use "her" (or "him"). In the plural, or when using "singular they" we use "they" as the subject, and "them" as the object.

Therefore your sentence 2 is not correct.